# creating digital signature usining SAS for Google API Geocode

Tags: sas, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I have key but don't know how can I create digital signatures using SAS.
I went through the links provided by google but they show creating digital signatures using other languages.
I don't which function/procedure to use in SAS to create digital signature in SAS.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Added some better tags.  Can you explain what needs to be done - ie, what does SAS need to create?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need the HMAC-SHA1 function.

I can suggest the following options:

1. You can try calling a Java library that supports this from SAS by using `javaobj` or JNI. (I think you can also access C libraries in a similar way).
2. Roll your own based on the spec: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt
3. Write a system shell script in php/perl/python (or even compile a utility app) that signs a string and then call it from SAS using the `X` statement or the `SYSTASK` facility.

Comment: I wrote my own SHA1 hash for another use, it's not terribly difficult.  I don't know if it's the same as the one desired here, but for a user who understands basic programming concepts it's a pretty easy implementation in SAS.  HMAC shouldn't be all that difficult either, I wouldn't think.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I don't have java installed on my system neither I know that language. However, I have some lacs addresses to be geocoded and passing each string to Java and getting the signature will take hell of time. Isn't there something in SAS or can't we create something like HMAC-SHA1 in SAS?